# VNH5019 motor controller

Tags: arduino, motor, dc-motor, arduino-uno, brushed-dc-motor

So I want to use the VNH5019 motor Controller shield for the Arduino Uno for a project. My question regarding this is the voltage of the motors. Since they differ from motor to motor I'm not sure which voltage works with the VNH5019. I haven't found any data in the regarding data sheet. Is there a way to tell the controller the max voltage that the motors could handle or how does this work? 
I'm quite new to this topic so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it the other way around.

- First decide what maximum voltage the motor must be running on (this could be the rated voltage or lower if you want that).
- Just apply this voltage to the VNH5019 motor Controller board as shown below indicated with `motor power`, but make sure this applied voltage is within the limits 5.5V to 24V.
- Using PWM you can vary the voltage that the board applies to the motor, ranging from 0V to applied voltage.

[image]